What are the methods of worship of lord Dattatreya for householders?
What are some devotional lyrics  and stotra that can be recited by a common householder to get the blessings of lord Dattatreya and get rid of deadly sins from our karmas ? Are there any books and scriptures which describe the worship of lord Dattatreya ? Thank you.

In the Narada Purana, the sage Narada Muni has spoken the Dattatreya Stotram.
Another one is Sri Datta Sharanashtakam:
I'm quite sure these can be recited by anyone, including householders.
These answers may also be useful.

This is kind of like a link only answer which isn't allowed on this site.

The former one is  so divinely soothing. From Sage Narada's time it has come down to us, we are so lucky and blessed. I heard this  stotra by Vaibhav Shete.

It truly is. https://youtu.be/E8EGrhDbXHM?si=TnVWZjdpEcmegKDt
